# Do I need to cleanup Rhino ScriptableObject instances?

Tags: java, javascript, memory-leaks, rhino

I am using Rhino in a project, which requires that I create a number of ScriptableObjects, which are used for a short time, and then discarded.  Will doing this create a memory leak?

The code is something like this:

```
Context cx = ContextFactory.getGlobal.enter();

try {
   for (String script : Scripts.findAll()) {
      Scriptable scope = cx.initStandardObjects();

      // load script into scope, and do something with it.

      // do I need to do any cleanup to for the scope?
   }
} finally {
   Context.exit();
}
```

Marko's solution is a good one.  I tested the scenario with jvisualvm, and found that garbage collection took care of the issue.

[image: Rhino Garbage Collection in action]

Comment: The oscillation in the loaded classes diagram is somewhat worrying: it seems that many short-lived classes are being dynamically generated. Performance may suffer.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik The large number of classes is likely caused by the Rhino implementation.  I tried using the profiler, but didn't have much luck.  Is there a tool that I can use to examine how many objects are created per method call?

Comment: I am not very familiar with the range of profiling tools available. `jvisualvm` alone can profile allocation and I think it also displays stacktraces for each allocation event, so there may be something similar to what you want. However, be careful to distinguish *object allocation* from *class loading*. The former is almost no problem at all as the JVM is highly tuned for massive allocation of short-lived object. The latter one is a totally different story: loading a class is a quite heavyweight operation and it must be followed by *class initialization*, which may not be a picnic either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe no cleanup is required, but if you want to dispell any worries, this is very easy to test. Just write an endless loop around the example you have posted and wait for a while. You can monitor the process with `jvisualvm` as well.